# How to explore files in alfresco via a web application server?

Tags: java, server, alfresco, connector, cmis

I'm a part of a project that needs to explore files in alfresco. Those files should be imported first from a web application server and then view them in alfresco like we explore any usual file in alfresco.

I want to know the steps to build a connector for this manipluation and what should I start with ?

PS : I already started studying the CMIS, am I in the right road ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, you are going right. Through CMIS you can export documents from your web application to Alfresco.

Comment: Are there specific steps to follow for building a custom connector between my application server and alfresco ? If you can give me an example what should I develop like classes in Java. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Please visit this link https://www.alfresco.com/cmis where you will find all the stuff regarding Alfresco CMIS.